# clicktag will mangle a long query string - how to work around it?

Tags: flash

For example:

http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect?data1=100&data2=200&data3=300">

Flash interprets the clicktag URL as: "http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect?data1=100"

How do you work around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the url using [htmlentities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp), otherwise the browser will interpret each "&" as the beggining of a different parameter:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect?data1=100&amp;data2=200&amp;data3=300
```